# How to convert SparseVector feature column to SparseMatrix (CSC format) in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

Struggling to find an efficient way to create SparseMatrix from SparseVectors column. Looking for suggestions/help to convert [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector) column to [SparseMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix.html#sparsematrix) in PySpark:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector
from operator import attrgetter

df = sc.parallelize([
    (SparseVector(3, [0, 2], [1.0, 3.0]), ),
    (SparseVector(3, [1], [4.0]), )
]).toDF(["features"])
```

> df.show()

```
+-------------------+
|           features|
+-------------------+
|(3,[0,2],[1.0,3.0])|
|      (3,[1],[4.0])|
+-------------------+
```

> Note: As far I do see from docs Sparse Matrix stored in CSC format.
> I'm looking for a simple and distributed approach to convert (I can
> create Scipy CSC using rdd and would like to avoid collecting to
> driver since is very large matrix).